# ASP.Net Identity 2.0 AccessFailedCount not incrementing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity

Last night I was working on a new project using FormsAuthentication and was customizing the ticket to include a security token so if the user logs off in one browser it logs off in all of them. In looking at the latest iteration of ASP.net Identity, it looks like it already has this functionality built in.

I created a new test MVC 5 web application with Individual Accounts enabled. Registration and authentication worked right out of the box.

However, I noticed that failed login attempts were not incrementing the **AccessFailedCount** field in the **AspNetUsers** table. And since that wasn't incrementing, I could try as many failed login attempts as I wanted without getting the account locked out.

How do I enable the AccessFailedCount and Lockout functionality on ASP.net Identity 2.0?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have to handle this manually. The `CheckPassword` method calls the `PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword` method to validate the password, but it does not update access failed count when the provided password does not match the existing one.

Here's an example of an authenticate method that supports lockout:

```
UserManager<User> userManager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore());

if (userManager.SupportsUserLockout && userManager.IsLockedOut(userId))
    return;

var user = userManager.FindById(userId);
if (userManager.CheckPassword(user, password))
{
    if (userManager.SupportsUserLockout && userManager.GetAccessFailedCount(userId) > 0)
    {
        userManager.ResetAccessFailedCount(userId);
    }

    // Authenticate user
}
else
{
    if (userManager.SupportsUserLockout && userManager.GetLockoutEnabled(userId))
    {
        userManager.AccessFailed(userId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping it wasn't a manual process. With all of the scattered configuration, leaky abstractions, and stuff you have to manually implement, I'm having a difficult time seeing the value of ASP.net Identity over the old FormsAuthentication system (unless you are utilizing the external auth providers).

Comment: SignInManager in version 2.1 is what will provide a higher level PasswordSignIn API that hides a lot of the complexity around lockout/twofactor, etc.

Comment: sure enough as @HaoKung said, in v2.2.1, which I just started a new project at, has this line `var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);` just change the `false` to `true`, for those who land here as I did and need this.

Comment: What to do if calling `AccessFailed` also doesn't iterate the `AccessFailedCount` and `SupportsUserLockout` is true?

Comment: Yes, we used to have our own implementation for asp.net 2.X authentication and authorisation to overcome the considerable failings of web forms default Authentication... am pretty amazed to find so many issues with asp.net identity so many years on. Can't MS find some decent developers?

Comment: Great Answer , I might add checking if the user is not already locked out in the  `else` statement like so : 


`if (userManager.SupportsUserLockout && await userManager.GetLockoutEnabledAsync(user) 
    && !await userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user))
{
    await userManager.AccessFailedAsync(user);
} `

Answer (score 18):

There is also the PasswordSignInAsync which accepts a "shouldLockout" argument. Setting this to true will auto increment failed login attempts

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
```

Comment: It would still seem that you need to call ResetAccessFailedCountAsync() if the user is successfully logged in.  No idea why that code isn't in the default project template.

Comment: Note that `AccessFailed` resets to `0` at the end of a 'fail' cycle. Once the maximum number of attempts has been reached, `AccessFailed` resets to `0` and `LockoutEndDateUtc` is set again. You only have access to the number of failed attempts within each `fail` cycle.

Comment: @JoelB This is default behavior now (at least in 2.2).

Answer (score 8):

For .NET Core 2.1 the ***shouldLockout*** is now named ***lockoutOnFailure***

So your login call should look like this to increment failed login attempts:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(loginModel.Email, loginModel.Password, loginModel.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
```

This will also reset the failed login attempts once the user logs in successfully.

Answer (score 0):

After unsuccessful login attempt , you should use

```
await UserManager.AccessFailedAsync(user);
```

**This codes increase AccessFailedCount**