# Web API 2 AccessFailedCount not Incrementing When using Token Based Authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity-2

I am using Webapi with Identity2.0  AccessFailedCount, LockoutEndDateUtc is not incermenting on Invalid UserName and Password. I have implement Token Based Authentication provided by WebAPI. Please help .

here is code Snippet

```
        using (UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = userManagerFactory)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }
            if (await userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id))
            {
                context.SetError("lock_out", "The account is locked.");
                return;
            }

            if (!userManager.IsEmailConfirmed(user.Id))
            {
                context.SetError("inactive_user", "The user is not active. Please check your Register Email to verify.");
                return;
            }

            ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
                context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user);
            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
            context.Validated(ticket);
            context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Finally I have resolved with this code

```
// To lock the user with userName ---- setting of maximum access 5 in IdentityConfig.cs File 
ApplicationUser userToLock = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);
if (userToLock != null)
{
    await userManager.AccessFailedAsync(userToLock.Id);
}
```

Now Access `AccessFailedCount`, `LockoutEndDateUtc` getting value

Thanks for the help guys. Special Thanks for @trailmax  ... To divert my thinking to webapi

Answer (score 3):

To increment `AccessFailedCount` on a user, every time the login is invalid you need to call for

```
await userManager.AccessFailedAsync(user.Id);
```

Otherwise this is not done for you in any way.

`ApplicationSignInManager` does this this for you but (as far as I know) this class only works with MVC, not WebAPI

Comment: where do you get this information? I have searched endlessly but simply cant find a good reference/tutorial its like dark magic.

Comment: @TinoMclaren AspNet Identity is open-source. I reviewed the source code.

Comment: yeah I deserved that, I downloaded Identity this morning from git but couldn't afford the time to try and work it out from source. In all honesty its getting bad if that's how we have to learn, not a fan.

Comment: @TinoMclaren reviewing the source code was my own desire because I blog about identity a lot. You don't have to do this, there are comprehensive examples/tutorials on asp.net that cover most of the bases.

Comment: The point im making is the examples/tutorials do not cover this issue as your blog clearly shows you struggling for months with this very subject - http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/06/asp-net-identity-user-lockout/ After skimming over this post your one line comment above 'I reviewed the source code' seems a little unfair. Yes you may have done this but it took you a while, maybe a good example/tutorial would have sped you along too. Anyhow +1 for your answer it really helped.

Comment: @TinoMclaren I would not call that struggling - I enjoy what I do. The update to that post was because I have answered somebody's question on SO and had to do a bit more research, so documented it further.

Comment: @TinoMclaren anyway, I'm glad this helped you and the problem is fixed for you!

Answer (score 1):

Hi It may be too late but I got some code from [ASP.Net Identity 2.0 AccessFailedCount not incrementing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207418/asp-net-identity-2-0-accessfailedcount-not-incrementing)

and customized to Web API.

```
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        bool EmailConfirmed = await userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id);

        if ( !EmailConfirmed)
        {
            context.SetError("inactive_user", "The user is not active. Please check your Register Email to verify.");
            return;
        }

        bool LockedOut = await userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id);
        if (userManager.SupportsUserLockout && LockedOut)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "This account has been locked out, please try again later.");
            return;
        }

        int FailedCount = await userManager.GetAccessFailedCountAsync(user.Id);
        bool LockoutEnabled = await userManager.GetLockoutEnabledAsync(user.Id);
        if (userManager.CheckPassword(user, context.Password))
        {
            if (userManager.SupportsUserLockout && LockoutEnabled && FailedCount > 0)
            {
                await userManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user.Id);
            }
            // Authenticate user
        }
        else
        {

            if (userManager.SupportsUserLockout && LockoutEnabled)
            {
                await userManager.AccessFailedAsync(user.Id);
            }
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }
```