# User Manager AccessFailed Async not incrementing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an issue with ASP.Net Identity, whenever I have AccessFailedAsync it doesn't update the user's access failed count even though the MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout is greater than 0. I've searched almost everywhere and still nothing helpful.

```
var _user =  _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userInfo).Result;
await _userManager.AccessFailedAsync(_user.Id);
```

the AccessFailedCount is always 0 no matter what happens.

Comment: How do you know it didn't increment it?

Comment: and are you certain `FindByIdAsync` is returning a valid `user` ?

Comment: @mjwills I checked the database and nothing is changed.

Comment: @Fraze yes it returns a correct a valid user

Comment: @MohamedHesham this may be a possible duplicate question.  See if this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381148/web-api-2-accessfailedcount-not-incrementing-when-using-token-based-authenticati

Comment: @Fraze Thanks but I've tried it too, and it doesn't update as well.