# Net core Identity lockout not lockout user account

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-identity

I try to enable lockout feature but I am not successed. Each time, I check database, AccessFailedCount is increase to 1 but after that again it turn to 0. What's wrong?

My codes are:

```
//Login page code

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null) {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

        if (ModelState.IsValid) {

            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.UserName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
            if (result.Succeeded) {

                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor) {
                return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut) {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
            }
            else {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return Page();
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }


//services code 
// Lockout settings.
options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 2;
options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
```

Comment: How did u get AccessFailedCount？Check the right way to get [AccessFailedCount](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24207769/13655939)

Comment: I am using .net core 3.1, so I didn't get AccessFailedCount. Because I expect signInManager handle it.

Comment: @is_oz what do you mean by "after that again it turn to 0."

Comment: I mean it is not lockout but count be 0 again. I figure out this question. If change lockout setting after adding user, old user does not effect. Only new user effect it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the User's `LockoutEnabled` column is set to true